# NodeJS re-run a command in a row

Tags: javascript, node.js

My question is like, i have a command in 10th line and i am trying to rerun it in 30th line. How can i do this? The detail of rerun command is in the code.

Javascript;

```js
import * as readline from 'node:readline/promises';
import { stdin as input, stdout as output } from 'node:process';
import * as fs from 'node:fs';
import moment from 'moment';
import * as process from 'node:process';

moment.locale("tr")
const saat = moment().format("DD MMMM dddd YYYY, HH:mm:ss");
const NotSaat = "["+saat+"]: "
const girdi = readline.createInterface({ input, output });

var GirisSorusu = await girdi.question("")

if(GirisSorusu.toLowerCase() == "hey therria" ||  "hey therria." || "hey therria!") {
 const heyterya = await girdi.question("Terya: Buyrun efendim?\n")
  if(heyterya.toLowerCase() == "not al" ||  "not al." || "not al!") {
   const nots = await girdi.question("Therria: Ne almamı istersiniz?\n")
   const NotRewrite = NotSaat + nots + "\n";
    fs.open("notlar/notlar.txt", "a", (err, fd)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log("Dosyaya erimeye çalışırken bir hata oluştu: " + err);
    }else{
        fs.write(fd, NotRewrite, async(err, bytes)=>{
            if(err){
                console.log("Dosyaya yazmaya çalışırken bir hata oluştu: ");
            }else{
                const notaldim = await girdi.question("Therria: Notunuzu aldım, başka bir isteğiniz var mı?\n") 
                 if(notaldim.toLowerCase == "yok" || "yok." || "yok!") {
                    await process.exit()
                 } else if (notaldim.toLowerCase == "evet" || "evet." || "evet!"); {
                    // Here is mine rerun command line, i want to rerun "heyterya" command
               } 
            }
        })        
    }
})
 }
}
```

Comment: you need to markup your code so we can tell which lines you are talking about.  Also, consider simplifying the question/example, and show what you have tried.

Comment: I explain which line is it, I repeat again. Its in the code written "Here is mine rerun command line, i want to rerun "heyterya" command. The heyterya command line starts with, const heyterya = await girdi.question("Therria: Buyrun efendim?\n");

Comment: In your original post you said 5th line, that’s’ the 15th line, a typo I think which added confusion. If you want to repeat the line, you will need to either use ‘let’ instead of ‘const’, or use a different variable e.g. ‘heyterya2’ to receive the result.